# C# VisualStudio grasshopper make a pManager[1] option if pManager[0] is int 0 or int1

Tags: c#, grasshopper

I hope will be enough clear in sharing my question.
C# in Visual Studio, I am trying to develop a grasshopper component.

I am interested in changing the behavior of the `pManager[1]`, it needs to be required input when `pMnager[0]= int 1` (as value) and to be optional when `pManager[0]= int 0`

In this way the component, after being compiled, will not ask for `pManager[1]` when the variable assigned to `pManager[0]` has a value equal to `int 0`;

```cs
pManager.AddIntegerParameter("A", "A", "description", GH_ParamAccess.item); //-->pManager[0]
pManager.AddTextParameter("B", "B", "Adescription", GH_ParamAccess.item); //-->pManager[1]
```

Thank you in advance!

A way to assign this behaviour to `PManager[0]`.

`pManager[1].Optional=true;` (or false) but I can't get the value assigned to `pManager[0]` (something like this `.GetValue() == 0;` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems I have solved it (or something like that):

directly in the `solverInstance`:

```
if (param0 == 0 )
  this.Params.Input[1].Optional = true;
else 
  this.Params.Input[1].Optional = false;
```